# Flex CallResponder works on initial click but not subsequent with I.E

Tags: apache-flex

I am working with Flash Builder 4.6 programming FLEX for a Transportation System Application.  They code below works great with Firefox when running on our server but for some reason when I use I.E. I only get the first response back from the click and subsequent clicks do not return what I need unless I'm running my I.E. 11 in debug mode.

Here is what it is supposed to do.  User clicks on a bus stop.  There is a button they can click that will hit a HTTP Service and return a json string with the next four buses to arrive and their times in a popup window.  They can close this popup window and if they click the "Click Here for Next 4 Bus Arrival Times" again it should refresh the list (In firefox this works, but with I.E. 11 I have to have debugging on for it to work, doesn't work without it only returns values for the first click, and subsequent clicks continue to show what's already in the list).

Yes, I'm new to programming flex and I'm sure I have some issues with the formatting and how I'm calling my code but I'm learning.  This is exciting to see work but I'm still having these issues.  Any ideas or advice are greatly appreciated.  I've tried to provide enough information but sorry if it's to much.  I'm thinking the issues in with my CallResponder somehow.  Thank you in advance for any help.  Perhaps something with the caching in I.E.?  I have run fiddler and it shows the initial request going through but when I click again it doesn't even send a request out.

```
    <esri:infoWindowRenderer>
                <fx:Component>
                    <esri:LabelDataRenderer label="Bus Stop on Selected Route">
                        <fx:Script>
                            <![CDATA[                                   
                                import flash.events.*;
                                import flash.sampler.NewObjectSample;

                                import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
                                import mx.controls.Alert;
                                import mx.controls.List;
                                import mx.controls.Text;
                                import mx.events.CloseEvent;
                                import mx.events.FlexEvent;
                                import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

                                import spark.components.Button;
                                import spark.components.TitleWindow;

                                protected function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
                                    var busStopLink:String = "http://rtcws.rtcsnv.com/mobile/geoRoutes.cfm?bsid=";
                                    var stopNumber:String = data.stopNumber;
                                    var urlString:String = busStopLink + stopNumber;
                                    var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(urlString);
                                    navigateToURL(urlReq, "_blank");
                                }

                                public var myTitleWindow:TitleWindow = new TitleWindow();

                                public function initApp():void {
                                    showBusTimesButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showBusTimes_clickHandler);   
                                }

                                public function showBusTimes_clickHandler(event:Event):void {
                                    var busEndpoint:String = "/rtcTimes/" + data.stopNumber;
                                    fetchBusTimesResult.token = busTimes.fetchBusTimes(busEndpoint);
                                    myTitleWindow = new TitleWindow();
                                    myTitleWindow.title = "Next 4 Bus Arrival Times for Stop: " + data.stopNumber;
                                    populateWindow();
                                    PopUpManager.addPopUp(myTitleWindow, this, true);
                                    PopUpManager.centerPopUp(myTitleWindow);
                                    myTitleWindow.addEventListener(CloseEvent.CLOSE, closeTitleWindow);
                                }

                                public function populateWindow():void {
                                    myTitleWindow.addElement(dataGrid);
                                }

                                public function closeTitleWindow(event:CloseEvent):void {
                                    PopUpManager.removePopUp(myTitleWindow);
                                }
                            ]]>                                                                                                                               
                        </fx:Script>
                        <fx:Declarations>
                            <s:CallResponder id="fetchBusTimesResult"/>
                            <bustimes:BusTimes id="busTimes"
                                               fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)"
                                               showBusyCursor="true"/>
                            <s:DataGrid id="dataGrid" dataProvider="{fetchBusTimesResult.lastResult}" sortableColumns="false"
                                        requestedRowCount="4">
                                <s:columns>
                                    <s:ArrayList>
                                        <s:GridColumn dataField="ROUTE" headerText="Route" resizable="false"></s:GridColumn>
                                        <s:GridColumn dataField="ARRIVAL" headerText="Arrival Time" resizable="false"></s:GridColumn>
                                        <s:GridColumn dataField="DIR" headerText="Direction" resizable="false"></s:GridColumn>
                                    </s:ArrayList>
                                </s:columns>
                                <s:typicalItem>
                                    <fx:Object ARRIVAL="ARRIVAL_TIME" ROUTE="ROUTE1" DIR="DIRECTION"></fx:Object>
                                </s:typicalItem>
                                <!--<s:AsyncListView list="{fetchBusTimesResult.lastResult}"/>-->
                            </s:DataGrid>
                        </fx:Declarations>
                        <s:VGroup paddingBottom="5" 
                                  paddingLeft="5"
                                  paddingRight="5"
                                  paddingTop="5"
                                  creationComplete="initApp();"> 
                            <s:Label text="Stop Number: {data.stopNumber}"/>
                            <s:Label text="Stop Name: {data.Stopname}"/>
                            <s:Label text="Route(s) Served: {data.routesServed}" />
                            <s:Button id="showBusTimesButton" label="Click Here for Next 4 Bus Arrival Times"/>

                        </s:VGroup>
                    </esri:LabelDataRenderer>
                </fx:Component>
            </esri:infoWindowRenderer>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather convoluted way of doing things, and not sure if it is intentional.

Why are you doing this:

```
                            public function populateWindow():void {
                                myTitleWindow.addElement(dataGrid);
                            }
```

Why cant you create a new MXML component, MyTitleWindow, and put all of your MXML markup in that title window, and in your calling class do something like this?

var busEndpoint:String = "/rtcTimes/" + data.stopNumber;

```
                                myTitleWindow = new MyTitleWindow();
                                myTitleWindow.title = "Next 4 Bus Arrival Times for Stop: " + data.stopNumber;
```

And in the creationComplete of your MyTitleWindow

fetchBusTimesResult.token = busTimes.fetchBusTimes(busEndpoint);

Comment: Why did I add the (dataGrid)?  I thought I had to add the (dataGrid) as an element otherwise it wouldn't show up in my popup window.  Thank you, being new to programming Flex this is all quite new to me so yeah, I'm sure I'm doing things the wrong way and the hard way to be honest.  I appreciate all the input and I will certainly look into applying your suggestions.   Now if I can figure out this caching issue.  I went into my html file and changed the following meta http-equiv tag to ="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-STORE" but it didn't help.  Perhaps I'm missing something somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it wasn't a callResponder issue it was a caching issue with I.E.  I figured out the caching issues with only I.E.  If I go into Tools->Internet Options->General->Settings under Browsing history-> and turn on “Every time I visit the webpage” it works just fine when I click on the Button to get the next 4 stop times (verified with fiddler I can click over and over and over and it sends requests all the time, compared to before when it would only send one and then cache the results).  Hence why when I was in debugging it would work as it requests new webpages since it's in debugging mode and then when I switched back to regular mode it didn't work.  I'm not sure if this is an absolute answer as users will have to turn this option on and asking the public to do this can be quite difficult but it's a work around.  I've tried modifying the meta tags as well to include the "pragma""no-cache" and the "Cache-control""no-store" and "Expires""-1" and none of those helped this issue.  I even added a  tag after the  tag as some have stated and it still wouldn't update the page and send my request.  If anyone has any other ideas I am open to them but for the time being this solution is just that, TEMPORARY BUT WORKS.